# Kafka transaction dirty reads

Tags: apache-kafka, transactions

I am trying to se if it is simple and possible to implement a ledger using Kafka.

I am basically trying to implement something that would match this example :
https://developer.confluent.io/learn/kafka-transactions-and-guarantees/#the-killer-feature-multi-operation-commits

As transactions in Kafka allow dirty reads, how can you be sure that you increment the latest balance ?
How can you be sure that no other transaction slip into the interval between when you read the balance value and when you update it ?

My current understanding of Kafka transactional producer and consumer is that it allows "dirty reads".

I can :

- start a first transaction T1,
- T1 reads ledger latest value
- start a second transaction T2,
- T2 reads ledger latest value
- T2 publishes a new value
- T2 is commited
- T1 publishes a new value (conflicting with T2 because it does not take into account T2 latest message)
- T1 is commited

Any idea of how to overcome this limitation ?